# How do I exclude 1 try if input is a string in a for loop for integer input

Tags: python

I am trying out a "guess the number game" as a personal project. I was successful initially, but ran into a problem. How do I make non-integer inputs not counted as a try for a for loop if user input a non-integer (eg. like a string or a float)?

MY CODE:

```
import random

print('Hi, what is your name')
name=input()

print('Hi '+ name + ' I am thinking of a number, make a guess')
secret = random.randint(1,6)
    
for guess in range (1,7):
    try:
        number = int(input())
        if number > secret:
            print ('Your guess is too large')
            
        elif number < secret:
            print('Your guess is too small')

        elif number != int:
            range(- 1)         #Do not consider non-integer as a try.
        
        else:
            break
    except:
        print('please input a number')

print('You took ' + str(guess) +' tries')
```

Comment: What do you want range(-1) to do?

Answer (score 0):

Why not put the if block outside the try and use continue

```
import random

print('Hi, what is your name')
name=input()

print('Hi '+ name + ' I am thinking of a number, make a guess')
secret = random.randint(1,6)
    
for guess in range (1,7):
  try:
    number = int(input())
  except ValueError:
    print ("please input number")
    continue

  if number > secret:
            print ('Your guess is too large')
            
  elif number < secret:
            print('Your guess is too small')
  
  elif number == secret:
            print("LOOOL Correct answer mind blowing")
```

Comment: The question was about how to not make an invalid guess, i.e a string or float count as an attempt, thereby meaning that the 'guess' variable must not increment. Using continue would mean that the guess variable increments even if an invalid answer is passed.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a for loop, you could simply use a while loop and maintain a counter which increments if it is a valid guess.

```py
counter = 0 #number of attempts
max_attempts = 6 #total number of attempts, you can change this 
while counter < max_attempts:
   try:
       guess = int(input())
   except:
       print("Please enter an integer")
       continue
   counter += 1 # valid guess therefore increments
   # enter if statements here
```